# mat-select binding with two columns

Tags: angular

I've a list of products and I'm trying to bind two bind with two columns.

HTML:

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Product</mat-label>
  <mat-select formControlName="pid">
    <mat-option value="">-all-</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let row of ds.listProduct" [value]="row.code"> 
     {{row.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

The below code it is working, but I want to bind one column more, like this:

```
[value]="row.code" && myCategory="row.category"
```

`myCategory` is a variable in my TS.

Is it possible and how can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You can add the other field in the same `[value]` using the `&&` operator if you want both the conditions to be `true`</s>

Since you want to display `mat-option` only for category `FUEL`. You'll have to use `*ngIf` to hide the rest of the options.

We'll have to move our `*ngFor` to `<ng-container>` as we cannot have multiple template bindings on a single container. To help us add `*ngIf` on `mat-option`.

Your code should look something like this:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
   <mat-label>Product</mat-label>
   <mat-select formControlName="pid">
     <mat-option value="">-all-</mat-option>
     <ng-container *ngFor="let row of ds.listProduct">
        <mat-option [value]="row.code" *ngIf="row.category === 'FUEL'"> 
           {{row.name}}
        </mat-option>
     </ng-container>
   </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

Note I used `row.category === 'FUEL'` in the `*ngIf`, you can use the `myCategory` instead of `FUEL` if you are setting in the `.ts` component

Comment: I tried using [value]="row.code && myCategory === row.category"  but the filter is not working. I want to show from my list only the product with category="FUEL"

Comment: Can you also share the `.ts` component? Do you want to send both the `row.code` and `row.category` to your .`ts` component?

Comment: @RafaelSegura Which list are you talking about, the `<mat-option>` list. or is there a different list in your HTML where you display the data?

Comment: I have a list of products with different categories, like this:
{code:"P01", name:"Diesel", category:"FUEL", price:20}, 
{code:"P02", name:"Gasoline", category:"FUEL", price:25}, 
{code:"P04", name:"Helix Ultra", category:"ADIT", price:20}
In mat-select-option I want to display only products with category="FUEL"

Comment: @RafaelSegura, I updated my answer to what I think you wanted to achieve. If it is still now what you want, can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: Thanks HassanMoin, I maked another list in .ts listProductFuel = this.listProduct.filter(r => r.category === 'FUEL'), but i preffer yours  adding *ngIf="row.category === 'FUEL'" in .html